# Wso2esb : Error while handling null value in switch case

Tags: switch-statement, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i'm using wso2esb 4.7.0 and wso2dss 3.1.0.i wish to select some column from table.For that i have used following query in dss :

```
select roleid,rolename,rolecode from mrole where clientid = ? and ModifiedOn = ?
```

It's working fine in dss as well as esb also.Output is like :

```
{"roleid":"1077282521908571","rolename":"adminrole","rolecode":"adminrole"},{"roleid":"1077282521908571","rolename":"adminrole","rolecode":"adminrole"},{"roleid":"1077278842127704","rolename":"everyonerole","rolecode":"everyonerole"},{"roleid":"1077282521908571","rolename":"adminrole","rolecode":"adminrole"}
```

this is one case.Now in second case if i didn't got modifiedon then obvious it shows error in dss like :

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: muser_DataService2.0
Location: /muser_DataService2.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: Select_Role_Details_Op
Current Params: {clientid=214057357158656, modifiedon=}
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

To solve that i'm using switch case in esb like :

```
 <switch source="get-property('ModifiedOn')">
            <case regex="''">
               <property name="ModifiedOn" value="0" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="ModifiedOn in case of null: "
                            expression="get-property('ModifiedOn')"/>
               </log>
            </case>           
 </switch>
```

it shows warning message in esb like :

```
[2014-10-08 11:43:54,100]  WARN - SwitchCase Provided character sequence for switch case condition is 'null'. Switch case will not be executed.
```

and without executing switch case it directly move forward and generate fault as well as dss shows error as above.How should i give the null condition in switch case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **boolean** xpath function to verify if your property exist :

```
<filter xpath="boolean(get-property('ModifiedOn'))">
   <then> 
      ...
   </then>
   <else>
      ...
   </else>
</filter>
```